# Keep original XML element sequence after transformation

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am working on XML transformation using XSLT. While transformation I am doing some ADD/DELETE/UPDATE operations on XML element and Attributes. I am expecting transformed file should be in same sequence as original xml file but it changes its attribute/element sequence. How can I preserve my original sequence?

Comment: XML element ordering is significant; XML attribute ordering is not.  You'll have to post your code to get help on element ordering; you'll have to process at a non-XML level to preserve attribute ordering (but you should really reconsider requirements regarding attribute ordering).

Comment: Duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348290/transformation-in-particular-sequence

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT node transformation in a predefined order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685357/xslt-node-transformation-in-a-predefined-order)